# Google Maps API does not render distance between two points

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm new to using Google API and I've been working on this project that is suppose to allow users to enter a starting point and a destination, and calculate how long it takes to get from point A to point B. However, I'm having trouble actually rendering the two points on the map. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

```
var myLatLng = {lat: 39.2904, lng: -76.6122}
var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};



var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

// create a Directions service to use the route method and get a result
var DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

// create a directions render
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);


function calcRoute(){
    var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("from").value,    
        destination:document.getElementById("to").value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
    }

    //Pass the request to the route method
    DirectionsService.route(request,function(result,status) {
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            const output = document.querySelector('#output');
            
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result); //display route
            output.innerHTML = "<div class='alert-info'>From: " + document.getElementById("from").value + ".<br />To: " + document.getElementById("to").value + ".<br /> Driving distance <i class='fas fa-road'></i> : " + result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text + ".<br />Duration <i class='fas fa-hourglass-start'></i> : " + result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text + ".</div>"
            
        }
        else{

            //delete route from map
            directionsDisplay.setDirections({ routes:[]});

            //center map in spain
            map.setCenter(myLatLng);
            output.innerHTML = "<div class='alert-danger'><i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Could not retrieve driving distance.</div>";
        }

    });

}

    // create autocomplete

    var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions:{
            country:['us']
        }
    }

    var input1 = document.getElementById("from");
    var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1,options);
    
    var input2 = document.getElementById("to");
    var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2,options);
    

  
    
    /* Ask to use location
    have both imperial and metric units */
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself), including any required HTML and CSS.

Comment: **AND** add debugging details. See [ask].